# How do I implement a granular IsDirty for each field in Catel?

Tags: catel

Catel's ModelBase supports an IsDirty property that changes if any property has changed.
Is there a mechanism to check for each property changing?
ModelBase implements something like this internally for the IEditableObject implementation using BackupData.
Is there a clean way to expose whether a single property has changed?

Comment: Have you implemented anything to support this?

Comment: @juicebyjustin no, I do not believe I actually did. I haven't worked with Catel, WPF or MVVM for man years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catel doesn't track actual field changes which are exposed to the outside. It should be fairly easy to implement a ModelChangeTracker which uses a combination of IEditableObject (to reset dirty states) and INotifyPropertyChanged.

You can implement it and create a pull request or request the feature at the official issue tracker:

http://www.catelproject.com/support/issue-tracker